# How to make this query on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

Customer table

[image]

Product Table

[image]

Customer_Product Table

[image]

I need to make query: **Search for customers who bought a certain product (for example, name = "toilet paper") at least 2 times**
I don't understand how.. I'm noob in databases.. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregation :

```
select c.name
from customer c inner join
     customer_product cp
     on cp.customer_id = c.customer_id inner join
     product p
     on p.product_id = cp.product_id
where p.lable = 'toilet paper'
group by c.name
having count(p.lable) > 1;
```